# Incorrect web url while using SP.ClientContext.get_current();

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, jsom, client-side-rendering

Using **JSOM** i am fetching the site URL. *Basically i want to get the current logged in user but nothing worked so thought of getting some basic script working.*

I am deploying this as an app on SharePoint server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', loadUserDetails);
    initializePeoplePicker();
});
function loadUserDetails() {

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    this.site = ctx.get_site();
    ctx.load(this.site );
    this.web = ctx.get_web();
    ctx.load(this.web);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));

}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    siteUrl = this.site.get_url();
    siteId = this.site.get_id();
    console.log(siteUrl);
    console.log(siteId);

}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

The issue is at `SP.ClientContext.get_current();` I am getting the directory path where i have deployed the .aspx file. 
[image]

And I get the end result as `Unexpected response data from server.`

In **CSOM** i get the user name of the server account. If i execute the code from my machine i am able to get my logged in details but the same code if i deploy on the server and then try to access SharePoint locally with my login then i still get the server account name.

The code for this i used is as below :

```
public static String GetLoggedInUserDisplayName(string SPHostUrl)
        {
            string loggedInUser = string.Empty;

            using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(SPHostUrl))
            {
                PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);
                PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name);
                context.Load(personProperties, p => p.DisplayName);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                loggedInUser = personProperties.DisplayName;
            }

            return loggedInUser;
        }
```

Comment: Is this a SharePoint-Hosted Add-in? Are you accessing your Add-in as an App Part (Client Part) inside the Host Web?

Comment: @MihailPopa Yes correct.

Comment: Well, App Parts are running inside iFrames, therefore the current context of the App Part will be different than the context of the page where the App Part is running on. Even so, you should be able to get the current logged in user.

Comment: @MihailPopa I see, the same approach should work you mean?

Comment: Well, I cannot say 100% that it will work, but I do not see why it should not. I think it is worth to try the second answer from this Stackoverflow question - it is very simple to implement and it works when used directly from the SharePoint Add-In: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981226/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-using-javascript

Comment: @MihailPopa Thank you. I have to hardcode the URL to get it working. Also `_spPageContextInfo` and `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` is undefined, even though im in SP page and i have loaded SP.js and most of the relevant .js files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57701/discussion-between-mihail-popa-and-ishan).